# AAM redirect http https double auth

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, alternate-access-mapping, https, credentials

I use SP2013, and I set AAM to redirect `http` to `https`.

When I browse `http://mysite` it asks for credentials, then redirect to `https://mysite` and asks for credentials again.

So the redirection works well, but why does it ask me for credentials twice?

Is that a normal behavior? Is there a way to solve this?

TIA

Comment: what are your AAM settings, are you using FQDN or server names?

Comment: I followed [this blog](http://blog.blksthl.com/2012/12/20/a-guide-to-https-and-secure-sockets-layer-in-sharepoint-2013/). So I used FQDN (with dns record).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use a redirect. Set your AAM to only https://, and then use the URL rewite module in IIS to rewrite http requests to https. There are guides (http://pcfromdc.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-redirect-from-http-to-https-with.html) out there to use the GUI, but I find editing the web.config file be easiest.

Install the URL Rewrite module for IIS and then insert the following into the web.config for the particular web application (on the line after the /handlers tag and before the /system.webServer tag:

```
</handlers>
      <rewrite>  
         <rules>  
          <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS Redirect" stopProcessing="true">  
            <match url="(.*)" />  
             <conditions>  
               <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />  
             </conditions>  
             <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />  
           </rule>  
         </rules>  
       </rewrite>
</system.webserver>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this module since I installed several ARR. But my wish was to avoid using other components that SharePoint. I'll take your solution if you tell me that AAM won't ever redirect my http->https without double authentication.

Comment: Normal behavious that if I had this rule in the web.config, I can't see it in IIS ? Or mb a reboot/iisreset is needed. Btw, that did the trick very well ... So many thanks for this idea.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the double authentication is normal behavior (could be wrong). And in IIS, if your talking about the rewrite rule you dropped into the web.config not showing up on the GUI for the rewrite module, that's normal too.